# Copy individual email address from Outlook 2013 address book?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, copy-paste, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a contact in my Outlook 2013 global address list. I would like to copy his email address so I can paste it into another program.

This appears to be strangely difficult. If I open the properties of the contact and go to the *E‑mail Addresses* tab, I see several email addresses for the contact but no option to copy/paste them.

Answer (score 1):

Half-way through posting the question, I found the answer.

From the contact properties page, click on "Actions". This pops out a small contact info screen. Under the *Send Email* header, the email address of the contact is shown. Right-click on it and choose *Copy*.

[image: screenshot of outlook]

<sub>I accidentally highlighted "Add to Contacts". The "Actions" button is actually next to this.</sub>